# Geometry and Geography datatypes in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqldatatypes

Can anyone give real example of geometry and geography datatypes in SQL server and explain me the purpose of them? I haven't seen use of these two datatypes anywhere. We have generic datatypes in sql server like varchar which can also be used to store such data. What is the benefit of using these two datatypes?

Comment: They provide you Spatial Capabilities. You may see: [Spatial Data Support In SQL Server 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd434647.aspx). Mostly is usage is related to Mapping, GIS applications

Comment: Your statement "We have generic datatypes in sql server like varchar..." could be applied to *any* data types you care to mention, not just these ones. Would you seriously advocate not using `int`, `datetime` or `decimal`?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: I got the point. I had just curiosity of these two data types and I haven't seen any real world example where I have seen the usage of these two datatypes. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**geometry** and **geography** are datatypes used for storing spatial information - describing the shape and position of objects in space (usually on the surface of the earth).

Why do you need a dedicated datatype for this sort of information? Think about how you would ORDER BY spatial information - it doesn't have a natural collation such as alphabetical for varchar, or chronological for date/time. And how would you write a query to identify features close to a given location - you can't SELECT * WHERE location BETWEEN 'Bristol' AND 'London'. So, ever since SQL Server 2008, there's been a whole range of methods (and indexes) specifically designed for doing these sorts of queries.

If you want practical examples of when they are used: an insurance company might use a geography field in a Customer table to record the location of every policyholder, and determine how many of them were likely to be affected by rising water levels by joining to a Rivers table which modelled river flood plains also in a geography field.
Or, you might want to determine the optimal location for a new store by analysing the geographic coverage of your (and your competitors) existing outlets.
Or, plan the optimal logistics route for a delivery vehicle, etc. etc.

Answer (score 3):

Can you calculate the area of a polygon on the earth's surface using just varchars?

If you can I imagine that it's much more complex and less clear than `Select @geog.STArea()`

The use is for storing data in the appropriate type, just like the XML type is better than a varchar for XML data, etc.

Comment: In addition to all people comments, They're internally same (both use binary DataType internally). So if you want to use data to represent it on the map or just represent it as a text or as a feed for a third party application (like GIS once), Then use Geometry and gain the performance. But if you need some calculation over saved data (Like sorting - get distances - get area - etc...) You should use Geography.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server supports two spatial data types: the geometry data type and the geography data type.

The geometry type represents data in a Euclidean (flat) coordinate system.
The geography type represents data in a round-earth coordinate system.

We can find it easily in sql server 2008 and higher.

create TABLE tab_spatial
(
id int IDENTITY (1,1) primary key,
zip nvarchar(20),
city nvarchar(500),
geo **geography**
);

[More about spatial data type](http://sqlcopy.blogspot.in/2013/04/sql-server-spatial-data-example-for.html)

Answer (score 1):

Ok i have an example for you.
   You have a table with 4 columns X1, Y1, X2, Y2. In this columns you have coordinates

```
x1=22.4109883
y1=44.740203
x2=22.4112528
y2=44.7404422
```

Now in this table you have also 3 columns declared as geometry:
GEOSTART,GEOEND,GEOSEGMENT

```
SET @sqlCommand = 'USE [' + @databaseName + '];' +
              ' UPDATE [dbo].[StreetsTable]' +
              ' SET [GEOSTART] = geometry::STGeomFromText(''POINT ('' + [X1] + '' '' + [Y1] + '')'', 4326) WHERE X1<>'''' and Y1<>'''' '; 
EXEC (@sqlCommand)


SET @sqlCommand = 'USE [' + @databaseName + '];' +
              ' UPDATE [dbo].[StreetsTable]' +
              ' SET [GEOEND] = geometry::STGeomFromText(''POINT ('' + [X2] + '' '' + [Y2] + '')'', 4326) WHERE X2<>'''' and Y2<>'''' ';
EXEC (@sqlCommand)

    SET @sqlCommand = 'USE [' + @databaseName + '];' +
                  ' UPDATE [dbo].[StreetsTable]' +
                  ' SET [GEOSEGMENT] = geometry::STGeomFromText(''LINESTRING('' + [X1] + '' '' + [Y1] + '', '' + [X2] + '' '' + [Y2] + '')'', 4326) WHERE X1<>'''' and Y1<>'''' and X2<>'''' and Y2<>'''' ';
EXEC (@sqlCommand)
```

After the update go and do a select on that table. Go on spatial results an select the spatial column. You will see the use of the geometry.

Hope it helps you